# Can two different binary trees can have identical post-order sequence

Tags: algorithms, trees, binary-trees

I have found that when drawing two trees having different structures, we can get the same in-order sequence and pre-order sequence. But I haven't found if two different binary trees can have an identical post-order sequence. Is it possible?

Comment: A trivial one but when all nodes contain the same value and nodes are equal in count

Comment: Look at this [`image`](https://imgur.com/a/nyRaAxn). Trees have same post order sequence. I presume it is safe to assume that trees that are mirror images  may have same post order sequence.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

If we allow nodes with 1 child to have that child in either position and consider the resulting trees distinct, the smallest such pair of trees has 2 nodes.

Tree 1 with traversal [b, a]:

```
   a
 b
```

Tree 2 with traversal [b, a]:

```
   a
     b
```

This is a somewhat unsatisfying answer, because the two trees are not really "different." If we increase the requirements by saying that two trees are the same iff their roots are the same and they have the same **non-empty** subtrees in the same order (this way, the two trees above are defined to be the same tree and so don't count), then the smallest such pair of trees has three nodes each.

Tree 1 with traversal [b, c, a]:

```
   a
 b   c
```

Tree 2 with traversal [b, c, a]:

```
    a
  c
b
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider any arbitrary binary tree and get its postorder sequence. Now starting from the root(the right-most element in the post order sequence) construct all possible [degenerate binary trees](http://www.cs.kent.edu/%7Edurand/CS2/Notes/10_Binary_Trees/ds_treesB.html). They all would have the same postorder sequence.

An example

```
                  1                 1           1          1          1
                 / \        =>     /           /            \          \
                2   3             3           3              3          3
            postorder = 231      /            \             /            \
                                2              2           2              2
```

For $n$ elements you have $2^{n-1}$ degenerate trees and the original tree having the same postorder sequence.